# jQuery autocomplete function brings the item from the database based on my typing word but result shows as just horizontal line of list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The jQuery autocomplete function brings the item from the database based on my typing word but result shows as just horizontal line of list. Attached image is showing how the result looks like.

[image: Result]

**HTML**:

```
<form class="navbar-seach pull-center">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Productstyle="width:550px; height:40px;padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 20px;" id="searchBox" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13) {searchResults(this.value); this.value = '';}">
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
include 'searchbox.php';

$switch_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'switch_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if (isset($_POST['name_startsWith']))
    $searchWordResults = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
else
    $searchWordResults = null;

switch($switch_id){
    case 1:
        $userObj = new searchBox();
        echo $userObj->autoComplete($searchWordResults);
        break;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#searchBox").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "class/searchbox_switch.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { name_startsWith: request.term, switch_id: 1 },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item){
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    };
                }));
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        searchResults(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

**PHP (searchbox.php)**:

```
include '../dbConnect.php';

class searchBox {
    public function autoComplete($name_startsWith) {
        $letterSearch = $name_startsWith . "%";
        $connectObj = new db_connect();
        $dbh = $connectObj->connect();

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE :start");
        $stnd = array();
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $letterSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stnd = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $json = json_encode($stnd);
        return $json;
    }

}
```

Comment: try to change your success  function to : success: function( data ) {              
                response(data);
            },

Comment: Hi B. Desai thanks for your advice. I have tried that before but It does not help. Can you guess any thing else? Thank you for taking your time to answer it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello @ETL are you getting proper result from ajax request? Please try: success: function(data) {console.log(data)}. And see what is your result in console.

Comment: Hi Desai, I am getting the proper data from ajax request but list are not appear in screen, instead some horizontal line shows. The number of horizontal lines are number of items found in the database based on what i type in the text box. Thank you so much for assisting me!

Comment: Will you please post here your json data which you are getting in success?

Comment: Hi Desai, my sql query has a where clause where product name like what i type in text box. six product name start with w in my database as a result, when i type w it brings 6 horizontal line, similarly i have 12 product name start with s, if i type s it brings 12 horizontal line. I dont know debuging that why i cant find exact result of my sql

Comment: add this line in success function: `console.log(data);` then from your browser's console copy this data and paste it here

Comment: Array[6]
0
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"
__proto__
:
Object
3
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"
__proto__
:
Object
4
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"
__proto__
:
Object
5
:
Object
product_name
:
"Water"

Comment: Desai, top comments is the array of products from console. Thank You for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it. You are passing wrong key in your result. Your result data key is "product_name" And You are trying to access "label ". Try This solution:

```
 success: function( data ) {                
          response( $.map( data, function(item) {                    
             return {
                   label: item.product_name,
             }
          }));                    

 },
```